# Angular 8 WebApi y EntityFramework en IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, angular8

estoy programando en el siguiente contexto

- Visual Studio 2019 con Framework 4.7 (no core)
- Angular js
- WebApi
- Entity Framework

Ahora bien, esto lo publico en un servidor con IIS y todo perfecto. Ahora he decidido hacer mi próximo proyecto con las mismas tecnologías pero cambiar de AngularJs a angular8.
Hay algo que no entiendo, angular8 corre bajo su propio servidor web cuando ejecutamos ng serve? entiendo que si, entonces como hago para que en el servidor de iis corran este y ademas el servidor se angular8?
Que cuando yo navego a mi proyecto ejemplo miserver.dominio.com/misitio
este me sirva la aplicacion angular la cual se conecta a la aplicación webapi con c#...
Muchas gracias

Comment: Ng serve te sirve para ejecutar el proyecto angular y utilizarlo como servidor local similar a lo que es iisexpress para .net, para usar el proyecto de angular en tu servidor iis ejecuta el comando ng build --prod para generar la compilación y el site listo para ser publicado en tu carpeta de iis. Espero te sirva saludos.

Comment: Gracias, esa parte no entendía conceptualmente, eso me genera la carpeta dist.

Comment: Asi es dentro de la carpeta dist esta todo el proyecto generado.